Do I need a one or two tail test?
I want to test whether there is a change in the 18O signature of the water column to the 18O signature of the sea floor.
I use the t test for this, but I also want to use a tail test. However, I am unsure whether I need a one tail or two tail test!
As I understand it, the one tail test speaks in favour of additionally determining the direction of the change, right? So that the 18O in the water column is greater or less than the 18O of the sediment bottom?
Do I understand that correctly

Weiss,
You definitely have the right idea. What statistical test you choose will always go back to what hypothesis and research questions you have. Dependent on that, either test could be 'correct.'
If you think that the water column (not sure your area of research or what a reasonable assumption would be about the water column) will decrease or increase compared to the sea floor, a one-tailed test would answer your question. The one tailed test will tell you if the change is less than or greater than the sea floor, but not both directions at the same time.
If you do not know where the change may be (which seems like it may be the case?), then a two tailed test will let you see if any difference exists at all, in either direction.
This is one of those great situations in statistics when coding both of your guesses and seeing how results compare out of curiosity isn't a bad idea!

I expect a decrease in 18O over time (which is my hypothesis for this Thesis) so as I understand you right one tail is right? thank you for your fast answer :)
